# How can spring-boot application easily get data from external GraphQL service?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, graphql

#### Background

My spring-boot-3 application need to get data from external GraphQL API. There I can/need fetch data by 4 different queries. I want to find some generic GraphQL Client with default GraphQL exceptions handling and default response conversion to objects.

---

#### Question

Is there any simple way to call GraphQL API? Any dependency or client for that?

---

#### Implementation that I have now

**GraphQLQueryLoader.class**

```java
@Slf4j
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@Component
public class GraphQLQueryLoader {

  private final ResourceLoader resourceLoader;

  /**
   * Query file should be in
   * <code>/resources/graphql/{fileName}.graphql</code>
   * */
  public String loadQuery(final String queryName) {
    try {
      final var location = "classpath:graphql/" + queryName + ".graphql";
      final var path = resourceLoader.getResource(location).getFile().getPath();
      return Files.readString(Paths.get(path));
    } catch (final Exception e) {
      log.error(String.format("Could not load GraphQL query (%s).", queryName), e);
      throw new GraphQLQueryException();
    }
  }

}
```

**GraphQLClient.class**

```java
@Slf4j
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class GraphQLClient {

  private static final Duration TIMEOUT = Duration.ofSeconds(30);

  private final WebClient webClient;
  private final GraphQLQueryLoader graphQLQueryLoader;

  public GraphQLResponse getByQueryName(final String query) {
    final var query = graphQLQueryLoader.loadQuery(query);
    return webClient.post()
                    .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                    .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                    .body(BodyInserters.fromValue(query))
                    .retrieve()
                    .onStatus(HttpStatusCode::is4xxClientError, handleClientError())
                    .onStatus(HttpStatusCode::is5xxServerError, handleServerError())
                    .bodyToMono(GraphQLResponse.class)
                    .block(TIMEOUT);
  }

  private Function<ClientResponse, Mono<? extends Throwable>> handleClientError() {
    return response -> response.bodyToMono(String.class)
                               .flatMap(body -> {
                                 log.warn("Client error with body: {}", body);
                                 return Mono.error(new HttpClientErrorException(response.statusCode(), "Client error"));
                               });
  }

  private Function<ClientResponse, Mono<? extends Throwable>> handleServerError() {
    return response -> response.bodyToMono(String.class)
                               .flatMap(body -> {
                                 log.warn("Server error with body: {}", body);
                                 return Mono.error(new HttpServerErrorException(response.statusCode(), "Server error"));
                               });
  }

}
```

**GraphQLResponse.class**

```java
public record GraphQLResponse(Object data) {}
```

**resources/graphql/my-query.graphql**

```
query myQuery() {
    myQuery(id: '123') {
        myCollection {
            items {
                title
                body
                action
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Usage**

```java
final var response = client.getByQueryName("my-query");
```

---

##### Is there any other easier way to get data from GraphQL API? Internet suggests only how to create GraphQL service, but nothing about any GraphQL client...

Comment: In my opinion, your current implementation is good and there is no easier way to achieve this.

Comment: If you are already using Spring for GraphQL that also provides a client (see https://docs.spring.io/spring-graphql/reference/client.html).

Answer (score 0):

`graphql-java-kickstart`, this library provides a convenient way to work with GraphQL in Java. You can refer to the official documentation for more details: [graphql-java-kickstart](https://www.graphql-java-kickstart.com/spring-boot/).

Comment: That's not what I am searching for. Documentation says: `graphql-spring-boot-starter` : turns your Spring Boot application into a GraphQL Server...